# Wordpress : How Can Write in .htaccess UTF 8 chars

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a htaccess file and i wont to write to it in utf 8 chars by php.

How can i do that.

Now when i write its show me like this :-

```
%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b6%d8%a9
```

Comment: no no ,, i need to set htaccess compatibly to write in utf

Comment: write url-decoded text `موضة`. `.htaccess` gets decoded text.

Comment: @Deadooshka i have page in `php`, from it i write into `htaccess` page, how can set `htaccess` read `utf-8`